# Apply OnLongClickListener to multiple Images with Same name

Tags: java, android, imageview, draggable, onclicklistener

So I have some code that listens for a drag of an ImageView however it only listens to the last one and I want it to listen to all of them. The problem is that the ImageViews are made dynamically and they all have the same name so it only applys to the last one.

Here is the ImageView creating code:

```
public ImageView getCardView(String Card) {

        imageView = new ImageView(this);

        switch (Card) {
            case "ace-clubs":
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.black_joker);
                imageView.setId(Integer.valueOf(CardId));
                break;
            case "ace-diamonds":
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ace_of_diamonds);
                imageView.setId(Integer.valueOf(CardId));
                break;

            case "ace-hearts":
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ace_of_hearts);
                imageView.setId(Integer.valueOf(CardId));
                break;
        }

        CardId++;

        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int padding_5dp = (int) (5 * scale + 0.5f);
        int Height = (int) (100 * scale + 0.5f);
        int Width = (int) (60 * scale + 0.5f);


        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Width, Height);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        imageView.setPadding(2, 0, 2, 0);
        params.rightMargin = 8;
        params.leftMargin = 8;

        return imageView;

    }
```

And here are the image listens that only apply to the last ImageView with the name:

```
imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());
                String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};

                ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),mimeTypes, item);
                View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(imageView);

                v.startDrag(dragData,myShadow,null,0);
                return true;
            }
        });

        imageView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction())
                {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                        layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");

                        // Do nothing
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                        x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                        x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");

                        // Do nothing
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                        Log.d(msg, "ACTION_DROP event");

                        // Do nothing
                        break;
                    default: break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(chosenCards);

                    imageView.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, imageView, 0);
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I am 100% sure to understand your question, but you should track the CardId of the last ImageView.

Comment: I don't understand...pls explain

Comment: @YudiMoszkowski

I think the best way to resolve your problem is to remove the OnLongClickListener object from the previous view and add it to the new imageView. 

`private OnLongClickListener listener; 
... 
lastImageView.setOnLongClickListener(null);
newImageView.setOnLongClickListener(listener) // which will become the lastImageView`